# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL when running graph

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am new to D3JS.
I was trying to run the graph script that was provided by http://www.d3noob.org, but it is not working on my site.

When running the following script:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
body { font: 12px Arial;}
path {
stroke: steelblue;
stroke-width: 2;
fill: none;
}
.axis path,
.axis line {
fill: none;
stroke: grey;
stroke-width: 1;
shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}
</style>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="d3/d3.js"></script>
<script>
var margin = {top: 30, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50},
width = 600 - margin.left - margin.right,
height = 270 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
var parseDate = d3.time.format("%d-%b-%y").parse;
var x = d3.time.scale().range([0, width]);
var y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]);
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x)
.orient("bottom").ticks(5);
var yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y)
.orient("left").ticks(5);
var valueline = d3.svg.line()
.x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
.y(function(d) { return y(d.close); });
var svg = d3.select("body")
.append("svg")
.attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
.attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
.append("g")
.attr("transform","translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + \
")");
// Get the data
d3.tsv("data/data.txt", function(error, data) {
data.forEach(function(d) {
d.date = parseDate(d.date);
d.close = +d.close;
});
// Scale the range of the data
x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date; }));
y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.close; })]);
svg.append("path") // Add the valueline path.
.attr("class", "line")
.attr("d", valueline(data));
svg.append("g") // Add the X Axis
.attr("class", "x axis")
.attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
.call(xAxis);
svg.append("g") // Add the Y Axis
.attr("class", "y axis")
.call(yAxis);
});
</script>
</body>
```

I get the following error message:

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

It goes wrong at line 39:

.attr("transform","translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + \

Comment: Code was copied from PDF, could that be the reason?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of:

```
.attr("transform","translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + \
")");
```

Try:

```
.attr("transform","translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
```

Comment: Great, now it works, what is the reason that it didn't work with \?

Comment: Just because it doesn't make any sense

Comment: Try understanding the code by writing it line by line instead of copying from pdfs

Comment: \ is not needed in JavaScript to continue a line.